# Is any air-to-air missile capable of re-engaging a target after missing?

Tags: missiles

Unfortunately this question is prompted by [missile performance in a community mod for DCS](https://youtu.be/vPYnEa2kXx0?t=653), where an Israeli Python-5 is depicted as missing its target, completing a vertical loop, then re-engaging and hitting the target.  The idea is really unbelievable to me, but I haven't kept up with modern air-to-air missile technology.  Is anyone claiming to possess missiles with re-attack or re-engagement capability?

I haven't found anything by Googling for "can air to air missiles re-attack" or "can air to air missiles re-engage".  I've seen claims that the Python 5 can engage "[any target at any angle, including backwards launch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(missile)#Python-5)" and I could see how a Lock On After Launch capability could be evolved into a Re-Attack capability, but they're clearly distinct.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about aviation, rather weapon technology.

Comment: @mins so are existing questions with upvotes and answers, like [Can anti-radiation missiles be used to target stealth fighter aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83657/can-anti-radiation-missiles-be-used-to-target-stealth-fighter-aircraft).  This is a question about military aviation.

Comment: Almost all homing weapon will try to engage something, and sometimes does engage something, after losing its original target.

Comment: @user3528438 do I need to clarify that I mean re-attacking the same target?  I mention the Python 5 looping around, but I could emphasize it more

Comment: @use3528438,  "*Almost all homing weapon will try to engage something*" This is not true. I cannot say with certainty that NO current AAM can do this, but the AIM-7 Sparrow, and the AIM-9 Sidewinder, and all Soviet AAMs when I was on active duty, absolutely cannot do this.

Comment: @Charles Bretana The aim-7 could re-engage on loss of RADAR lock on the F/A-18A. The hornet tilts the RADAR planner array forward and out of the way. A flood horn located behind is then used to blast the whole area with RF energy in the hope that the missile will get some sort of a reflection off the target. I suppose it comes down to the definition of missing. If breaking primary lock on a non-fire-and-forget missile would otherwise cause the missile to not receive steering commands, that's as good as missing in my book,

Comment: @Craig re-acquisition of target after losing lock, but while the target's still in front of you, isn't quite what I had in mind with this question, though it is interesting

Comment: @Craig,  In the F-4 (USAF) this was called Wide gate. We also had a flood antenna. The doppler speed gate in the missile would sweep the entire range of possible velocity doppler frequencies. But it would almost always lock on to the ground return (Main Beam Clutter).

Answer (score 5):

Yes... there are two missiles air to air (Python 4/5) that could "re-engaging" its bandits!

The following diagram is reproduced from ["Air Power Australia" by Dr. Carlo Kopp](http://www.ausairpower.net/TE-Gen-4-AAM-97.html). ausairpower.net/TE-Gen-4-AAM-97.html[image: Example Python 4 Engagement Geometry - Launch Aircraft (F-18) is passing nearly abeam (labeled ">60 degree off-boresight angle" a High-G Manoeuvering Target (Su-27) and launches a Python 4 AAM. The missile turns hard into the target, which is in a 9G Sustained Turn, and misses its First Hit Opportunity, but continues its turn and intercepts at a Second Hit Opportunity.]

Comment: interesting!  what's the source for that diagram?

Comment: From the famous "Air Power Australia" by Dr. Carlo Kopp... http://www.ausairpower.net/TE-Gen-4-AAM-97.html